# Cant import wx using pycharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm, wxpython

Im using PyCharm and when I try to use wxPython im getting error.

right on the beginning of the file I get this:

```
import wx
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

I downloaded wxpython using pip.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My assumption here is that you installed wxpython outside of the virtual environment that you are using in your pycharm project.

So the solution is to install it in your virtual environment.

You can check your virtual environment in PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter. There you can also press the + symbol at the bottom left to install wxpython there. (Which will basically pip install the package inside the virtualenv your project uses.)

Comment: I have done it in this way and installed the wxpython 4.0.1. And I could see that in my site-packages, but I don't why I keep getting the error of ModuelNotFoundError.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, click File menu, choose Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter. The add button should be on the right side of the screen (v. 2018.2.4 Community).